# Make function that merges two lists of ints into list of tuples

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to create a function with below specification:

- it takes two lists of distinct ints as input and outputs list of tuples <int?, int?>,
- the structure of the tuple must be either (a, a), (a, null) or (null, a),
- the order of the tuples in the result list is irrelevant.

**Cases**:

*Case 1*

```
Input: [] , []

Output: []
```

*Case 2*

```
Input: [4, 2, 3, 1 ] , [ 1, 2, 3, 4]

Output: [(4,4), (2,2), (3,3), (1,1)]
```

*Case 3*

```
Input: [4, 2, 3, 1] , []

Output: [(4, null), (2,null), (3,null), (1,null)]
```

*Case 4*

```
Input: [] , [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

Output: [(null, 1), (null,2), (null,3), (null,4)]
```

*Case 5*

```
Input: [ 1, 2, 5] , [ 1, 2, 3, 4]

Output: [(1, 1), (2,2), (5,null), (null,3), (null,4)]
```

**My implementation (C#)**

Below is my implementation of the Function and it seems to work. However, it seems not to be very optimal and I am searching for a better approach.

```
  internal static List<Tuple<int?, int?>> PairInts(List<int> firstList, List<int> secondList)
    {
        List<Tuple<int?, int?>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int?, int?>>();
        List<int> firstListBackup = new List<int>(firstList);
        List<int> secondListBackup = new List<int>(secondList);

        foreach (int val in firstList)
        {
            foreach (int val2 in secondList)
            {
                if (val == val2)
                {
                    pairs.Add(new Tuple<int?, int?>(val, val2));
                    firstListBackup.Remove(firstListBackup.Where(v => v == val).FirstOrDefault());
                    secondListBackup.Remove(secondListBackup.Where(v => v == val2).FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (int val in firstListBackup)
        {
            pairs.Add(new Tuple<int?, int?>(val, null));
        }

        foreach (int val in secondListBackup)
        {
            pairs.Add(new Tuple<int?, int?>(null, val));
        }

        return pairs;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible for list to have duplicates? Like `[1,1,2]`?

Comment: No, there are only distinct values in the list. I will update the specification, thank you!

Comment: I doesn't even matter if the list can have duplicates or not.

Comment: If you sort the two input lists, then it becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can be achieved in the LINQ way.

1. `listOne` left join `listTwo` by number. Mae sure to convert `listTwo` as `List<int?>` first. This returns the result with both `a` and `b` have value or `a` has value.
2. Result from 1 merge (vertially) with `listTwo` for those `listTwo`'s values don't exist in the result from 1.

```cs
public static List<Tuple<int?, int?>> AddPairs(List<int> listOne, List<int> listTwo)
{
    var result = (from a in listOne
            join b in listTwo.Select(x => (int?)x) on a equals b into ab
            from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select Tuple.Create<int?, int?>(a,b)
           ).ToList();

    return result
        .Concat(listTwo.Where(x => !result.Any(y => y.Item1 == x))
               .Select(x => Tuple.Create<int?, int?>(null,x)))
        .ToList();
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aFiGYq)

Comment: What's the time complexity of this solution?

Comment: @Maurycyt my guess would be `O(max(n,m)*m)` =)

Comment: Yeah and as OP wrote "However, it seems not to be very optimal and I am searching for a better approach." it would seem they were looking for something better than quadratic, which means that honestly I have no idea why this answer was accepted. But oh well, what can one do when a user decides that a problem which isn't solved is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of complexity the best possible what you can expect is O(n + m). Use `HashSet` to build searchable in [`O(1)` (average) collection](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/):

```cs
internal static List<Tuple<int?, int?>> PairInts(List<int> firstList, List<int> secondList)
{
    var hashFirst = new HashSet<int>(firstList); // O(n)
    var hashSecond = new HashSet<int>(secondList); // O(m)

    var result = new List<Tuple<int?, int?>>(firstList.Count + secondList.Count);
    
    foreach (var i in firstList)  // O(n)
    {
        int? r = i;
        int? l = null;
        if (hashSecond.Contains(i)) // O(1)
        {
            l = i;
        }

        result.Add(Tuple.Create(r, l));
    }
    
    foreach (var i in secondList)  // O(m)
    {
        int? l = i;
        if (!hashFirst.Contains(i)) // O(1)
        {
            result.Add(Tuple.Create((int?)null, l));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that for small n and/or m algorithms with worse Big-O complexity can be faster.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach that I find intuitive is to create three sets of `a`s; one set for each of the three possible `Tuple` structures.

We know we want to create `Tuple`s having the following structures:

1. `(a, a)` when both lists contain `a`
2. `(a, null)` when only the *first* list conatins `a`
3. `(null, a)` when only the *second* list contains `a`

To create `(a, a)`, we need to find the items that are present in both lists.
Items that are present in both lists can be found by producing the *intersection* of the lists.

To create `(a, null)` and `(null, a)`, we need to find items that are present in one list, but not the other.
Items that are present in exactly one of two lists can be found by producing a *set difference* of the two lists.

If we use *System.Linq*, we can

- produce the *intersection* of the two lists by using [`.Intersect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0): `{ }.Intersect({ })`
- produce a *set difference* of the two lists by using [`.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0): `{ }.Except({ })`

**Note:**
`listA.Except(listB)` and `listB.Except(listA)` will create sets containing *different* values; whereas `listA.Intersect(listB)` and `listB.Intersect(listA)` will create sets containing the same set of values.

---

I find the following implementation (returning an `IEnumerable` rather than a `List`, utilizing the `yield` keyword) to be quite straight-forward and easy to read:

```csharp
internal static IEnumerable<Tuple<int?, int?>> PairInts(List<int?> first, List<int?> second)
{
    foreach (var match in first.Intersect(second))
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(match, match);
    }
    
    foreach (var inFirst in first.Except(second))
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(inFirst, (int?)null);
    }
    
    foreach (var inSecond in second.Except(first))
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create((int?)null, inSecond);
    }
}
```

If you need a `List`, it can simply be created from the result of that method:

```
var result = PairInts(list1, list2).ToList();
```

---

An implementation actually returning a `List` could look like the following:

```csharp
internal static List<Tuple<int?, int?>> PairInts(List<int?> first, List<int?> second)
{
    var pairs = new List<Tuple<int?, int?>>();
    
    pairs.AddRange(first.Intersect(second)
        .Select(match => Tuple.Create(match, match)));
    
    pairs.AddRange(first.Except(second)
        .Select(inFirst => Tuple.Create(inFirst, (int?)null)));
    
    pairs.AddRange(second.Except(first)
        .Select(inSecond => Tuple.Create((int?)null, inSecond)));
    
    return pairs;
}
```

Here, [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) (also from the *System.Linq* namespace) is being used to create a `Tuple` object for each item in each of the sets.

Alternatively, you could use `foreach` and `.Add()` rather than `.AddRange()` and `.Select()` by replacing:

```csharp
pairs.AddRange(first.Intersect(second)
    .Select(match => Tuple.Create(match, match)));
```

with

```csharp
foreach (var match in first.Intersect(second))
{
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(match, match));
}
```

and so on.

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IbnCj4).

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable in O(nlog(n)) and O(n).

### O(nlog(n))

Sort both lists. This way, you can then linearly traverse both lists checking if an element exists in both lists or not. Some pseudo-code (since I'm not fluent in C# and do not how std::tuple<> works in C++):

```cs
firstList.sort();
secondList.sort();
int firstIndex = 0, secondIndex = 0;
int firstSize = firstList.size(), secondSize = secondList.size();
List<Tuple<int?, int?>> output;

while (firstIndex < firstSize && secondIndex < secondSize) {
  if (firstList[firstIndex] < secondList[secondIndex]) {
    output.Add(firstList[firstIndex], null);
    firstIndex++;
    continue;
  }
  if (firstList[firstIndex] > secondList[secondIndex]) {
    output.Add(null, secondList[secondIndex]);
    secondIndex++;
    continue;
  }
  output.Add(firstList[firstIndex], secondList[secondIndex]);
  firstIndex++;
  secondIndex++;
}

// Now we just need to "empty" the other, potentially non-empty list.
while (firstIndex < firstSize) {
  output.Add(firstList[firstIndex++], null);
}
while (secondIndex < secondSize) {
  output.Add(null, secondList[secondIndex++]);
}
```

This works because every time you can instantly tell if a matching element exists in the "other" list. Simply iterate over the lists in an ascending manner, increasing either index when appropriate.

Potential problem: List may not be easy to sort, but you can linearly convert it to an array.

Also, sorting itself in this case can be done linearly via radix sort, but that's not a very elementary method. Nonetheless, this solution could technically be O(n).

### O(n)

This solution involves a HashMap (it has this name in Java, in C++ it's called an unordered_map, I don't know what it's called in C#). Hashmaps provide constant-time access to keys.

First, convert both lists into hashmaps of numbers of occurences of each value. For instance, for input

```
[2, 2, 3], [1, 2]
```

you'd receive the following hasmaps

```
{(2, 2), (3, 1)}, {(1, 1), (2, 1)}
```

Then, iterate over the keys of one hashmap checking whether they exist in the other hashmap. If so, add them to the output list in the form `(a,a)`, removing `a` from both hasmaps. Otherwise, add `(a,null)`. Then, the second hashmap might not be empty so you have to iterate over the remaining elements of the other hashmap to add the elements of the form `(null,a)` to your output.

In this example, you'd first "see" the key `2` in the first hashmap, with a value of `2`, meaning it occurred twice in the first list. The key `2` occurs with value `1` in the second hashmap, so you add `(2, 2)` to the output, and then add `(2, null)` to your output. Now, the hashmaps need to be modified to look like this:

```
{(3, 1)}, {(1, 1)}
```

Now you "see" element `3` in the first hashmap, so you add `(3, null)` into the output, because `3` does not occur in the second hashmap.

Lastly, you will notice that the second hashmap has a leftover element and so you add `(null, 1)` to your output.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
internal static List<Tuple<int?, int?>> PairInts(List<int> firstList, List<int> secondList)
{
    var pairs = new List<Tuple<int?, int?>>();

    foreach (var firstItem in firstList)
    {
        var removedAnyItems = secondList.Remove(firstItem); // Try to remove any corresponding items

        pairs.Add(new Tuple<int?, int?>(firstItem, removedAnyItems ? firstItem : null)); // If removed, it will be (a, a). If it cannot be removed, it will be (a, null)
    }

    foreach (var secondItem in secondList) // Since we removed any corresponding items, this list will not have any corresponding item in first list. So it will be always (null, a)
    {
        pairs.Add(new Tuple<int?, int?>(null, secondItem));
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this produce a wrong output? I think it matches numbers as-is and can put pairs of the form (a,b) into the output list, when it is stated that they must be of the form (a,a), if both elements are to be not-null. I believe this isn't "simplified code" because first and foremost, it's not equivalent to what OP wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method using LinQ namespace that is optimized.

```
public static List<(int?, int?)> GetPairs(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
{
    var pairs = new List<(int?, int?)>();
    var firstNullableList = list1.ConvertAll(x => (int?)x);
    var secondNullableList = list2.ConvertAll(x => (int?)x);
    pairs = firstNullableList.ConvertAll(x => (x, secondNullableList.Find(y => y == x)));
    pairs.AddRange(secondNullableList.ConvertAll(x => (firstNullableList.Find(y => y == x), x)).Where(x => !pairs.Contains(x)));
    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: While _"LinQ namespace is optimized."_ does not mean that it's usage is. Provided code complexity look to me as `O(n^2)`, not to mention that this will lead to repeated pairs.

Comment: @GuruStron sorry, but it will not include duplicate pairs cause of that `Where.`

Comment: Yes, agreed, missed that part (was checking from phone). Though complexity issue still stands.